# Why asp.net textboxes loses jquery upon editing?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have put jquery masks on my textboxes.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
     $("#txtBoxLawyerCNIC").mask("99999-9999999-9", { placeholder: "" });
     $("#txtBoxLawyerContactNo").mask("+99-999-9999999", { placeholder: "" });
});


 <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtBoxLawyerCNIC" placeholder="XXXXX-XXXXXXX-X" MaxLength="15" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="form-control">
 </asp:TextBox>
```

It works until I click `edit` button in gridview which calls `RowCommand` and textboxes losses all the Masking. Why ?

```
protected void grdviewLawyers_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int LawyerID = Convert.ToInt32(grdviewLawyers.DataKeys[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)].Value);
        short UserID = Convert.ToInt16(Session["UserID"]);

        if (e.CommandName == "cmdEdit")
        {

            DataTable dt = MngLawyers.SelectLawyersByLawyerID(LawyerID);
            DataRow r = dt.Rows[0];


            txtBoxLawyerCNIC.Text = r["LawyerCNICNo"].ToString();
            txtBoxLawyerContactNo.Text = r["LawyerContactNo"].ToString();

        }
}
```

Why it loses masks upon RowCommand ?

Comment: Is the gridview in an updatepanel or something like that?

Comment: if `grdviewLawyers_RowCommand` is called then an HTTP request has been made. this will refresh the page. You need to ensure the JS to set the masks is called after postbacks.

Comment: @Richard one cannot call it from server side

Comment: Any markup within an updatepanel needs to have jQuery handlers reattached.  You can use pagerequestmanager to access event after load finished to reattach.

Comment: sir I ma naive and don't understand this, please help with syntax etc plase

Comment: @BrianMains thanks! this was my exact problem. I just rebound the datepicker after each load and it works perfectly now

Answer (score 0):

For me it's a long time ago that I used ASP.NET web forms but I remember me that the compiler translate the id of the asp tags are renamed. In the most cases it was only the name of the page plus the name you have given in your asp-tag. I'm not 100% sure of the last thing I've said is correct. In fact, you can inspect the element in your browser for get the new name.

You can do that for Google Chrome by left click on the text blok and select **Inspect** or by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>. After if you can see a html input-tag in this case I've done that for the text area to make a new answer from Stack Overflow.

[image]

On the developer tool window you can see the new id of that element and you must use this in your client code.

Comment: @Juventustech: No, I'm sorry. It's to long ago I've programmed whit ASP web forms. second, I'm also a junior in programming so I've no experience enough for find a good solution for helping you, sir.